# What is Anchor Peer in Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperldger-fabric-peer

There is step while configuring fabric network to update anchor peer. There is one anchor peer per organization, but not able to understand why do we need anchor peer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A peer node on a channel that all other peers can discover and communicate with. Each Member on a channel has an **anchor peer** (or multiple anchor peers to prevent single point of failure), **allowing for peers belonging to different Members to discover all existing peers on a channel**.

> You can read about this in glossary on hyperledjer fabric web site:
>
> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/glossary.html#anchor-peer

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: It would be noteworthy that the link is for release 1.1., to see the latest go to https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary.html#anchor-peer .

Answer (score 9):

Anchors peers encoded into config update transaction in order to enable communication between peers of different organizations and discover all active participants of the channel.

Comment: Understood. Can you tell me why anchor peers require these separate .tx files that the Orderer needs to be aware of?. I was reading BYFN (read the docs) of Fabric,

Comment: Because it configures two anchor peers, one for each organization and only peer of the organization allowed to update it. Hence you have two transactions which has to submitted by one peer from each organization respectively

Answer (score 0):

A designated peer node for a specific Member on a channel that other Members’ peers can discover and communicate with
Allows peers belonging to different Members to discover all existing peers on a channel
Can designate multiple Anchor peer.